# Not able to access dictionary value in Macro DBT

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am accessing a dictionary variable which is defined in the marco

```
{% macro normalize_state(column_name) -%}
{% set states_dict = {
    "Alabama" : "AL",
    "Alaska" : "AK",
    ...
    ....
} -%}

CASE WHEN {{column_name}} IS NOT NULL THEN '{{ states_dict.get(column_name) }}'
ELSE NULL END
{%- endmacro %}
```

But  `'{{ states_dict.get(column_name) }}'` produced the output `None`

Comment: I tested this and it actually works on my end. Are you sure that `column_name` contains the exact same values as the ones presented as keys in the dictionary? Because that's what you are doing there :)

Answer (score 2):

Macros are compiled (templated) before the query is run. That means that the data in your database doesn't run through the jinja templater.

`{{ states_dict.get(column_name) }}` looks up the `name` of the column in your dictionary, not the data it contains.

What you need to do is use your dictionary to write a case statement that performs the `get` operation. That looks like this:

```sql
{% macro normalize_state(column_name) -%}
{% set states_dict = {
    "Alabama" : "AL",
    "Alaska" : "AK",
    ...
} -%}
case
    {% for k, v in states_dict.items() %}
    when {{ column_name }} = '{{ k }}'
    then '{{ v }}'
    {% endfor %}
end
{%- endmacro %}
```

Then you need to pass in `column_name` as a string (quoted) when you call the macro:

```sql
select {{ normalize_state("my_column") }}
```